# Modal not appearing when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this has been asked a lot but I couldn't find a solution to my problem so here it is: my modal does not appear upon clicking. My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modalBtn").click(function() {
    $(".modal").fadeIn();
    $(".modal_main").show();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").click(function() {
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />

<button class="btn btn-success" id="modalBtn">Uploads</button>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal_content"></div>
  <div class="modal_main">
    <h1 class="modalUpload">Uploads</h1>
    <hr class="modalLine">
    <div class="updates col-md-12">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case you are using bootstrap modal, you can just do `$('.modal').modal('show')`

Comment: And also you need to add the bootstrap.js .

Comment: I made a snippet for you the way you could have done it.

Answer (score 0):

See here this would be working:

You need to add

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

in the button. Cause if you don't: If you click on the button you also click on the body ...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modalBtn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('clicked modal button');
        $(".modal").fadeIn();
        $(".modal_main").show();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").click(function(){
        console.log('clicked body');
        $(".modal").fadeOut();
        $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```css
.modal {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="modalBtn">Uploads</button>

<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal_content"></div>
    <div class="modal_main">
    <h1 class="modalUpload">Uploads</h1>
    <hr class="modalLine">
        <div class="updates col-md-12">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next is your code which was not working: The problem was you clicked on the button but also on the body... See the console log

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modalBtn").click(function(event){
        console.log('clicked modal button');
        $(".modal").fadeIn();
        $(".modal_main").show();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").click(function(){
        console.log('clicked body');
        $(".modal").fadeOut();
        $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```css
.modal {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="modalBtn">Uploads</button>

<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal_content"></div>
    <div class="modal_main">
    <h1 class="modalUpload">Uploads</h1>
    <hr class="modalLine">
        <div class="updates col-md-12">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop bubbling the onClick button event. You can simply return false. 
[Here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) you can find a good article about bubbling and capturing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#modalBtn").click(function() {
        $(".modal").fadeIn();
        $(".modal_main").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```